# how to bind values in dropdownlist from sql table in MVC4?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on matrimonial site registration page... I want to know how to take the values from sql database and bind it to dropdownlist on the registration page?
How to bind values to dropdownlist from sql table in c# MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** "how to take the values from sql database"

**A:** You may use some ORM layer(EntityFramework, Linq2SQL, ...) or [native SQL queries executed via SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx).

**Q:** " how to bind values in dropdownlist from sql table in c# MVC4?"

**A:** [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-DropDownList-6ef6ffcb) is one possibile solution